# C program ending after taking input in VS Code External Terminal

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I made this changes in the executor map to run the program in the external termina:
"code-runner.executorMap": {
"cpp": "g++ $fullFileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt.exe && start $fileNameWithoutExt.exe"
}

The program did start to run in the external terminal but it ends after taking the input.
Here is the simple C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x,y,l,a,b;
    printf("Enter the bottom left co-ordinates of the square: ");
    scanf(" %d %d", &x, &y);
    printf("Enter the length of the square: ");
    scanf(" %d", &l);
    printf("Enter the co-ordinates to be checked: ");
    scanf(" %d %d", &a, &b);
    if((a>=x && a<=(x+l)) && (b>=y && b<=(y+l))) //boundary limits for four sides of the square
    {
        printf("\n%d,%d lies inside the square.", a,b);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%d,%d don't lie inside the square.", a,b);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

[image]

The program then ends after taking the input. Please help me to solve this problem of VS Code.

Comment: You need to debug your program

Comment: The windows closes after the program ends. So you either need to run the program in a debugger or add some code at the end of the program to prevent it from immediately ending (e.g. call `getchar()`)

Comment: @bolov After debugging. The program only takes input. And then doesn't send any output.

Comment: @kaylum I did call getchar(); but still it ends without processing input. How do I run the program in the debugger?

Comment: Add a `\n` at the end of the `printf` strings to ensure the output is flushed before the `getchar()`.

Comment: try adding `system("pause");` before `return 0` and add `#include <stdlib.h>` at the beginning of the code.

Comment: @kaylum 
```#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a , b;
    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    scanf(" %d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("Their sum is %d", a+b);
    return 0;
}```
Can you please edit this for me.

Comment: @ionizer It worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You program urns but the window will be closed because it will exit. You need to keep the window open after the program has ended:

```
{ "cpp": "g++ $fullFileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt.exe && start /wait $fileNameWithoutExt.exe" }
```

The /wait option for the command start will run the command-prompt with the /k option which ensures that.

Comment: ```"c": "g++ $fullFileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt.exe && start /wait $fileNameWithoutExt.exe",```

```start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:129
+ ...  -o temp_conversion.exe ; if ($?) { start /wait temp_conversion.exe }
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand```

Getting this error.